# Best way to implement a toggle button in AngularJS Material

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-material

I am looking for a simple solution to implement a toggle button with a custom selected / unselected icon in AngularJS Material.

The functionality should be identical to the md-checkbox (with ng-model for the selection state), but I want to have my own icon displayed for selected / unselected state. md-checkbox does not seem to support custom icons, and md-button lacks the ng-model.

Preferably I would like to avoid implementing a custom directive and only make this work through css. Is this possible with AngularJS Material?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can define a `toggle function` to create toggle activity in your controller, like this:

```js
$scope.toggle = function() {
    $scope.variable = !$scope.variable
    console.log($scope.variable);
}
```

Button on the html:

```html
<md-button 
    ng-click="toggle()"
    ng-class="{'active': variable, 'disable': !variable}">
```

Answer (score 6):

After some digging the best solution currently seems to be using an md-button, which allows custom icons, and extending it with `ng-click` and `ng-class` like this:

```html
<md-button ng-click="selected = !selected"
           ng-class="{'selected-button' : selected}">
```

This takes care of the selection state. And in CSS I can then set the styles for the *selected-button* class

Even though the solution is rather simple, I think there should be an out-of-the-box support from Angular Material for a toggle button (or checkbox) with custom icons.

Comment: not sure why, but `ng-click="selected = !selected"` didn't work for me, implementing a `toggle()` function in my controller did work.

Answer (score 2):

Properly using all classes of Angular Material v1.x

```html
<md-button class="md-icon-button"
        ng-click="filterToggle = !filterToggle"
        ng-class="{'md-primary md-raised' : filterToggle}">
    <md-tooltip md-direction="bottom">Filter</md-tooltip>
    <md-icon ng-hide="filterToggle">filter_list</md-icon>
    <md-icon ng-show="filterToggle">clear_all</md-icon>
</md-button>
```

in controller set

```js
$scope.filterToggle = false;
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('CommentController', function($scope) {
  $scope.filterToggle = true;
  //start function.
  $scope.StartFunc = function() {
    $scope.filterToggle = false;
    console.log('in pause function.');
  };
  $scope.CallFunc = function() {
    $scope.filterToggle ? $scope.StartFunc() : $scope.PauseFunc();
  }
  // pause function.
  $scope.PauseFunc = function() {
    $scope.filterToggle = true;
    console.log('in pause function.');
  }
})
```

```html
<link href="https://material.angularjs.org/1.1.2/angular-material.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://material.angularjs.org/1.1.2/angular-material.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="CommentController">
    <md-input-container>
      <md-button class="md-icon-button md-primary md-raised" ng-click="CallFunc()">
        <md-tooltip md-direction="bottom">Start/Pause Func</md-tooltip>
        <md-icon ng-hide="filterToggle" style="background-color:grey;width:auto;">pause</md-icon>
        <md-icon ng-show="filterToggle" style="background-color:grey;width:auto;">play_arrow</md-icon>
      </md-button>
    </md-input-container>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's normaly considered good form to explain your suggestions/answers. Code only answers can be surprisingly uninformative, even if they are technically correct.